# How do I fix my paragraph element text not aligning in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using my flexbox I am unable to get the `p` elements within the "newDog" `div`. I want them all to line up on the left side so that I can uniformly move them underneath the dl contents.

Here is the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: rgb(255, 222, 176);
}
#newDog{
    display: flex;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
#newDog img{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    clear: both
    
}
#newDog dl{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
#newDog p{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: inherit;
    align-self: flex-start;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zk3.png" alt="Aussies R Us" title="Aussies R Us">
        <h1>&#9886; Our Aussies &#9887;</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
        <a href="ouraussies.html">Our Aussies</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
        <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
        <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
    </nav>

    <main>
        <div id="newDog">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/R3l8.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Max" title="Max">
            <dl>
                <dd>Name: Max</dd>
                <dd>Availablility: Not Available</dd>
                <dd>Breed: Standard Australian Shepherd</dd>
                <dd>Gender: Male</dd>
                <dd>Height: 20-25 inches</dd>
                <dd>Weight: 50-60 lbs</dd>
                <dd>Age: 1-2 Years old</dd>
                <dd>Activity Level: Medium - High</dd>
            </dl>
                <p>
                    Meet Max! He is a great young Australian Shepherd, he is a very smart dog, and learns quickly. <br>
                    Max loves to be around people, even though he is not a very good lap dog, he never <br>
                    wants to be left out of the fun, and will stick around wherever there is people. Max <br>
                    loves other animals, small and big. He is very gentle when being introduced to other <br>
                    animals, and tends to watch after his smaller brothers.
                </p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="newDog">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o2Kp.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Odyn" title="Odyn">
                <dl>
                    <dd>Name: Odyn</dd>
                    <dd>Availablility: Not Available</dd>
                    <dd>Breed: Mini Australian Shepherd</dd>
                    <dd>Gender: Male</dd>
                    <dd>Height: 14-18 inches</dd>
                    <dd>Weight: 15-25 lbs</dd>
                    <dd>Age: 4-5 Months old</dd>
                    <dd>Activity Level: Low - Medium</dd>
                </dl>
                <p>
                    Meet Odyn! He is a young pup that is looking to find a good lap to lay on and sleep! <br>
                    Odyn loves to play with his brothers Max and Jack Jack, but he also loves a good nap. <br>
                    If you are looking for a pup to laydown and watch a show with, Odyn is the pup for you!
                </p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="newDog">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MWy.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Jack Jack" title="Jack Jack">
                <dl>
                    <dd>Name: Jack Jack</dd>
                    <dd>Availablility: Not Available</dd>
                    <dd>Breed: Yorkie</dd>
                    <dd>Gender: Male</dd>
                    <dd>Height: 7-9 inches</dd>
                    <dd>Weight: 14-18 lbs</dd>
                    <dd>Age: 3-4 Years old</dd>
                    <dd>Activity Level: Low - Medium</dd>
                </dl>
                <p>
                    Meet Jack Jack! He isn't exactly an Aussie pup, but he is a cute guy nonetheless. Jack <br>
                    loves to chill out and sit on someones lap even more than his brother Odyn. Don't let <br>
                    that fool you though, when Jack wants to play, he plays! Jack Jack, loves to wrestle <br>
                    with his cat friend Meep. Sometimes he wins, sometimes Meep wins, its a never ending battle!
                </p>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>&copy; 20 R Us</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Reproducing your code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io) will be more helpful.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tlh38/pen/OJbbLwj

Comment: On a side note ids **must** be unique. Use the class attribute and selector instead for "newDog"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping your text content, the DL and P tag portion of your code in a div, give it a class of `info` to control padding. Then change newdog ID to a class and with `display: flex;` there will be no need to float the image element. naturally, the `dl` will place above the `p` tag then. I also suggest a reset for your padding and margin in your css. This way your not chasing any hidden browser padding or margin issues. Lastly, I suggest removing the BR tags in your P tag, unless you want the breaks to be there, this will let the view port do that work for you.

Note on ID's... ***Id attribute should always be unique to one single element. If you want to have a common style for multiple elements, use a class.*** Hence I changed the `newdog` ***id*** to a ***class***.

*Also, you may want to consider @media queries in your CSS as well for different size screens to make your images and text content fit on smaller screens in a more user friendly format.* With that, view this snippit in full screen mode =)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 222, 176);
}

.newDog {
  display: flex;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.info {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.newDog dl {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5em 0 2em;
}

.newDog p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zb8Wvk3.png" alt="Aussies R Us" title="Aussies R Us">
    <h1>&#9886; Our Aussies &#9887;</h1>

  </header>

  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
    <a href="ouraussies.html">Our Aussies</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
    <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
    <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a> &nbsp; &#9475; &nbsp;
  </nav>

  <main>
    <div class="newDog">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/R3yolM8.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Max" title="Max">
      <div class="info">
        <dl>
          <dd>Name: Max</dd>
          <dd>Availablility: Not Available</dd>
          <dd>Breed: Standard Australian Shepherd</dd>
          <dd>Gender: Male</dd>
          <dd>Height: 20-25 inches</dd>
          <dd>Weight: 50-60 lbs</dd>
          <dd>Age: 1-2 Years old</dd>
          <dd>Activity Level: Medium - High</dd>
        </dl>
        <p>
          Meet Max! He is a great young Australian Shepherd, he is a very smart dog, and learns quickly. Max loves to be around people, even though he is not a very good lap dog, he never wants to be left out of the fun, and will stick around wherever there is people. Max loves other animals, small and big. He is very gentle when being introduced to other animals, and tends to watch after his smaller brothers.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="newDog">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o2KAyxp.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Odyn" title="Odyn">
      <div class="info">
        <dl>
          <dd>Name: Odyn</dd>
          <dd>Availablility: Not Available</dd>
          <dd>Breed: Mini Australian Shepherd</dd>
          <dd>Gender: Male</dd>
          <dd>Height: 14-18 inches</dd>
          <dd>Weight: 15-25 lbs</dd>
          <dd>Age: 4-5 Months old</dd>
          <dd>Activity Level: Low - Medium</dd>
        </dl>
        <p>
          Meet Odyn! He is a young pup that is looking to find a good lap to lay on and sleep! Odyn loves to play with his brothers Max and Jack Jack, but he also loves a good nap. If you are looking for a pup to laydown and watch a show with, Odyn is the pup for you!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="newDog">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MDBBTWy.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Jack Jack" title="Jack Jack">
      <div class="info">
      <dl>
        <dd>Name: Jack Jack</dd>
        <dd>Availablility: Not Available</dd>
        <dd>Breed: Yorkie</dd>
        <dd>Gender: Male</dd>
        <dd>Height: 7-9 inches</dd>
        <dd>Weight: 14-18 lbs</dd>
        <dd>Age: 3-4 Years old</dd>
        <dd>Activity Level: Low - Medium</dd>
      </dl>
      <p>
        Meet Jack Jack! He isn't exactly an Aussie pup, but he is a cute guy nonetheless. Jack loves to chill out and sit on someones lap even more than his brother Odyn. Don't let that fool you though, when Jack wants to play, he plays! Jack, loves to wrestle with his cat friend Meep. Sometimes he wins, sometimes Meep wins, its a never ending battle!
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>&copy; 2021 Aussies R Us</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Wrap all the p tag inside the dl tag ,So that it comes as per your requirement